# Многопоточность с использованием семафора

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qtcreator

Задание:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю, как это сделать: имеется семафор с максимальным кол-вом потоков = 2. При нажатии на кнопку создается новый поток и встает в очередь, если семафор занят. Пытаюсь сделать это в QTcreator, но не могу понять где что объявлять.

Comment: показывайте, что уже у Вас получилось.

Comment: @KoVadim в том то и дело, что я даже не могу начать. Не могу понять как объявить семафор и т.д.

Comment: там все просто -  `QSemaphore sem(2);` но вот только поможет ли это...

Comment: @KoVadim Если бы это было так просто. Нужно использовать WinAPI

Comment: @Николай Балыков Вы уже нашли функцию WInAPI для создания семафора?

Comment: @НиколайБалыков ну как бы в msdn легко найти функцию [CreateSemaphore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createsemaphorew) и рядом даже [пример есть](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/sync/using-semaphore-objects). Правда я опять сомневаюсь, что это поможет.